# How can I get json from an API and display it in HTML?

Tags: html, node.js, rest, express, fetch

I started to learn Nodejs and made an API for a mysql database.

The GET request work and looks like this when I call http://localhost:3000/client for example :

```
{
    "error": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "IDC": 1,
            "Nom": "Dupond",
            "Prenom": "Jean",
            "DateNaiss": "01/01/1980",
            "Adresse": "1 Place de la République Marseille",
            "DatePermis": "01/01/2000"
        },
        {
            "IDC": 2,
            "Nom": "Pignon",
            "Prenom": "Francois",
            "DateNaiss": "20/04/1996",
            "Adresse": "2 Place de la République Marseille",
            "DatePermis": "01/01/2017"
        },
        {
            "IDC": 3,
            "Nom": "Leblanc",
            "Prenom": "Juste",
            "DateNaiss": "01/01/1996",
            "Adresse": "3 Place de la République Marseille",
            "DatePermis": "01/01/2019"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Liste clients"
}
```

Now I made a new project and want to make a website to get the data from my API and display it in a pretty HTML table, then add buttons to create and edit data... But I realize I have no idea how to do it properly.
I only managed to display the Json in the console.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const fetch = require("node-fetch");


// URL par défaut
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/client';
fetch(url)
  .then((res) => { 
    return res.json() 
  })
  .then((jsonData) => {
    console.log(jsonData);
    //It's probably here that I need to write HTML, but how does it work ?
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
 });
//-------------------------------------
 app.listen(3001, function () {
     console.log('Node app is running on port 3001');
 });
 module.exports = app;
```

How can I get data from my API and display it in a table ?

Comment: Hi your request should be on frontend, why are you making request on backend ?? Use javascript on frontend and from html page make request and display data

Comment: You're right actually I didn't think of it. Still pretty new to all this sorry !
But where should I write my HTML+JS then ? Something below `app.get('/', function (req, res) {` that would say "If you go to this page then use this index.html file" ?
And that way I could send the data to that page so my fetch wouldn't be useless.

Comment: Check this sample: https://medium.com/@atingenkay/creating-a-todo-app-with-node-js-express-8fa51f39b16f or search some express starter template to see how it is done

Answer (score 0):

In your first `then` you'r declaring a parameter called `res`. You should call it something like `data` and return it inside the `res.json`.

So your line `.then((res) => {` should be `.then((data) => {`

And your line `return res.json()` should be `return res.json(data)`

You was actually overriding the `res` parameters comming from `express`. So your `res.json()` wasn't working at all. Plus, to send datas to the frontend (the user) you'v to pass the data to the method you use (`res.json(data)`, `res.send(data)`, `res.write(data)` etc..)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and corrections !

I don't get where I should write my HTML and where to write something like "for each client in data write <li>client.nom" etc. This is the main part I'm struggling,

Comment: You can add HTML as string format like this : `res.send("<h1>How are you ?</h1><p>Good thanks</p>")`